# How can I use XGboost in foreach and doParallel in R?

Tags: r, xgboost, parallel-foreach

I'm having a problem while trying to run xgboost inside a foreach with doParallel, I'm using a AMD Naples with 32 cores and 64 threads. The run gets stuck with this part of code, I would like to have the results of the last line of the block inside a list in order.

```
 pg = list()

 c1  = makeCluster(20)
 registerDoParallel(c1)

 result <- foreach(i=1:100,.combine=combine,.inorder=TRUE,.packages=c("data.table","plyr","Matrix","dplyr","xgboost$)) %dopar% {

   temp = unlist(p[i])
   index_1 = temp[1]
   index_2 = temp[2]
   v1 = unlist(group_list[index_1])
   v2 = unlist(group_list[index_2])
   v = append(v1,v2) 
   pg[i] = list(v)
   d = data[,v]

   x = data.table(d)
   trainMatrix <- x[,lapply(.SD,as.numeric)] %>% as.matrix
   out <- xgb.cv(data = trainMatrix, label = y, nrounds = 1000,objective = "binary:logistic",nthread = 4,eta=0.5,max_depth = 12,eval_metric="error",nfold = 10,prediction = TRUE,verbose = FALSE)  
   out$evaluation_log[5]$test_error_mean
 }
 stopCluster(c1)
```

foreach seems not working properly

Comment: What do you mean `it gets stuck`? And `seems not working properly`? Please show that 1 iteration works before attempting 100 iterations.

Comment: Package `xgboost` has built in parrelization. (i believe this is one of the benefits of the XGBoost algorithm, which makes parallel processing easier). Using `foreach` on a single machine will just create increased competition for resources. There may be a benefit for multiple machines.

Comment: ... and take a look at the `caret` package. this provides common wrappers for multiple algorithms with consistent interfaces and syntax. It also integrates parallel processing somewhat automatically. Some docs at https://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel-processing.html

Comment: @CPak the process does not come to an end and the last question was about "is there something wrong with my code in the way I used the foreach".

Comment: @epi99 I know, 
I need to build many models, and I wanted to parallelize this construction, not just run an xgboost, use doParallel and forach in an AMD Naples would not be correct to parallel this process?

Comment: @igormor - `it does not come to an end` - I don't think you've provided convincing evidence your code is **not working**. It could be working but taking longer than you expect. If you run 1 iteration, about how long does it take? Now, you are running 100 iterations on only 32 cores.

Comment: @CPak  I ran an iteration only and it took 3.2 minutes. using a non-parallel like this:  result = as.vector(0) and  for (i in 1:length(p)) it takes 9 seconds in 100 iterations. My real problem has a large n, 100 iterations is only a example

Comment: @igormor - 1 ) your example has 100 iterations x 1000 rounds of cross validation - thats a lot!. 2) you are giving 4 threads to each invocation and 20 parallel threads to the cluster which is 20x4 = 80 threads . Scale back to a small version that runs, then increase steadily watching cpu. 3) i am no expert here, but your full data is 
 copied into every thread.Find a way to chunk your data https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf has some guidance on chunking data

Comment: @epi99  OK! I'll try!

Comment: Are you running in Linux system? I am experiencing the same issue. It is easy to prove it even with a super tiny example, hence it is not a memory or patience issue. It is connected to this: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2094 (OpenMP and fork parallelization do not get along together). Unfortunately, I have no solution, yet.

Comment: @Jav Yes, I'm running in a Linux system. I follow the link posted by @epi99 and I solved my problem using chunking by allocating the rows of my matrix in a vector and using an iterator to send a block of rows each to core,  like this:  `result <- foreach(i=iter(pg,by='row',chunksize=c1),.combine=cbind,.inorder=TRUE,.packages=c("data.table","plyr","Matrix","dplyr","xgboost","doParallel")) %dopar% { ... }`

Comment: @igormr glad you found a solution :) . I ended up recompiling xgboost without openmp as I didn't need that kind of parallisation for tasks I was running on that machine.